# listen for RFID scanner and print data

Tags: java, rfid

I have an RFID reader/scanner that I bought from this site [E-Gizmo](http://www.e-gizmo.com/KIT/RFID%20reader.html) and they have a manual here: [Low Cost RFID Reader Manual](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxdLxDCD6HidR0V0UW5DdEgxZkE/view).
I've been trying to get it to work with java and so far, I have almost zero idea how to do this.

what I want to do is to have a class running on the background(threading+Listener? not sure.) that waits for the RFID and store the content of the tag into a variable(String).

so far, I got my class to read the physical port of the device. Here is my code.

```
package Data;

import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ComControl{
    public static void main (String argsp[]){

        SerialPort ports[] = SerialPort.getCommPorts();

        for(SerialPort port: ports){
            System.out.println(port.getDescriptivePortName());
        }

        Scanner i = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = i.nextInt();

        SerialPort port = ports[x-1];

        if(port.openPort()){
            System.out.println("Port is open");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Port is not available");
            return;
        }

        port.setComPortParameters(9600, 8, 0, 0);
        port.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_SEMI_BLOCKING, 0, 0);
        Scanner data = new Scanner(port.getInputStream());

//I just had to give it a try or guess..
        do{
            System.out.print(data.nextLine());
        }while(x<99);

    }
}
```

Ive been browsing around and so far, I havnt found any newbie friendly guides on how to get my device to work with java.

what I currently have in my tools are `jSerialComm-1.3.10.jar` and `comm-2.0.jar`

any hints, guides, or probably code that might help?

Comment: imo, their manual is really well written, from what I could see they define the exact protocol of communication and give example Arduino code (`c`) which should not be that hard to port over to java

Comment: yes, I was able to understand the code even though I dont know C or Arduino, but how to get I/O of the device to java, well thats my crisis. if I get the I/O to work then that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [JSSC](https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-simple-serial-connector/) with great success before, it is imo the best serial library for java, I have always had trouble with rxtx:

[Linked](https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-simple-serial-connector/wikis/jSSC_examples.wiki) is an example of how to use the lib for your comms with the scanner

Comment: oh YES! thanks for the goodies! I can clearly understand this one! I had goosebumbs because of the excitement when I read the codes. Im gonna give this a try! THANK YOU!